# Cannot read property 'password' of undefined at Query._callback Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

While implementing passport and working the backend for it i got this error. Could anyone help me figure out how to fix it?

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined
>       at Query._callback (/Users/oscarstein/Documents/Programering/express-cc/app.js:76:32)

Using the following code:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
      console.log(username);
      console.log(password);
      const db = require('./db');

      db.query('SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE username = ?', [username], function(err, results, fields){
        if (err) {done(err)};

        if (results.length == 0) {
          done(null, false);
        }

        const hash = results[0].password.toString();

        bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function(err, response){
            if (response == true) {
              return done(null, {user_id: results[0].id});
            } else {
              return done(null, false);
            }

          });
      })

    }
));
```

Comment: Console log your `results` right above `const hash = results[0]...` line. My guess is DB is returning a non array.

Answer (score 1):

Consider these lines of code

```
if (err) {done(err)};

if (results.length == 0) {
    done(null, false);
}
```

It checks for error existence, then executes function `done(err)` and the function flow goes on.

Then it checks if there are results, calls function `done(null, false)` and the flow goes on again.

Correct way of doing this is

```
if (err) {
    return done(err)
}

if (results.length == 0) {
    return done(null, false);
}
```

Notice **return** statement above. It breaks further code execution inside of this callback function.

Comment: Or you can rewrite your code using `if/else` blocks, but it looks uglier, to be honest.

Answer (score -1):

Check if the table from the database has a field called 'password'

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.